# Lambda cannot put object to amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to resize my Image when user uploads an image to my bucket. The push notification of image is working. And lambda is running as well. However I cannot put object to the s3 bucket. It gives `Access Denied` error.

If my source bucket is `source-bucket` and destination is `destination-bucket`, the policy of the role associated with my lambda function is as follows:

```
{ 
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket",
          "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
        ]
    },
    {
  "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "s3:GetObject"
      ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket",
          "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Answer Update**

Turns out I was updating the ACL and did not add the ACL put permission. So the following solved my problem:

```
{ 
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:PutObject",
          "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket",
          "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
        ]
    },
    {
  "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "s3:GetObject"
      ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket",
          "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The way I debug is to allow all actions `s3:*` and if it works, then make the policy more granualr.

Comment: wow thanks. it worked. Now I have to shortlist the combination.